# What is the meaning of "un poco" in "un poco adagio"?

Tags: tempo

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo#Basic_tempo_markings) *Adagio* means:

> *Adagio* – slow and stately (literally, "at ease") (66–76 bpm)

In Shumann's "Grosse Sonate" op. 11, the tempo marking is "*Un poco adagio*" :

[image]

what does this mean? According to [Glossary of musical terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_musical_terminology#U) "*Un poco*" means

> **un poco** or **un peu**
>     A little

So does this mean that *Un poco adagio* a little bit faster or a little bit slower than *Adagio*? And how fast is that approximately in beats per minute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most will interpret this as meaning "a little bit faster than Adagio." In other words, it's not *totally* slow, just *a little bit* slow, thus with a slightly higher BPM than a "true" Adagio.

In terms of giving an actual BPM for *un poco Adagio*, that's much more difficult. Everyone will have a different interpretation of the tempo; check out [Perahia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruV4V5mPwW8), [Kissin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-ZrqXG1kEs), and [Pollini](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-l7U-I-6w4) to see what you might like best.

Comment: Interesting to compare the different performances on Youtube. I am not sure what tempo I like the best yet, but at least I think it should be as you say a little be faster than Adagio.